# Trying to speed up this for loop but I can't using Callable implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

This is the sequential loop:

```
  private boolean canSpawnVehicle(SpawnPoint spawnPoint) {
// TODO: can be made much faster.
Rectangle2D noVehicleZone = spawnPoint.getNoVehicleZone();
for(VehicleSimView vehicle : vinToVehicles.values()) {
  if (vehicle.getShape().intersects(noVehicleZone)) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

}

This is my attempt at threading through an executor service and a callable implementation class:

```
  private boolean canSpawnVehicle(SpawnPoint spawnPoint) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
  // TODO: can be made much faster.
  Rectangle2D noVehicleZone = spawnPoint.getNoVehicleZone();
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
  Future<Boolean> future;
  for (VehicleSimView vehicle : vinToVehicles.values()) {
      future = executor.submit(new CanSpawnThread(vehicle, noVehicleZone));
      if(!future.get()){
          return false;
      }
  }
  executor.shutdown();
  return true;
```

}

This is the thread class:

public class CanSpawnThread implements Callable {

```
private VehicleSimView vehicle;
private Rectangle2D noVehicleZone;

public CanSpawnThread(VehicleSimView vehicle, Rectangle2D noVehicleZone){
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
    this.noVehicleZone = noVehicleZone;
}

public Boolean call() {
    boolean can = true;
    if (vehicle.getShape().intersects(noVehicleZone)){
        can = false;
    }
        return can;
}
```

}

Comment: `if(!future.get())` you are blocking in the loop until each one is finished before starting the next. No wonder if isn't speeding up!

Comment: i understand what you're saying but i can't figure out then where to place the get method in the loop

Comment: And what is your question? You stated your goal, you posted some code, but what now? Is the code not working, is not giving enough speedup? So: please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with a parallelStream assuming the list has enough items to justify the threads. 
I haven't tested this though.

```
private boolean canSpawnVehicle(SpawnPoint spawnPoint) {
    Rectangle2D noVehicleZone = spawnPoint.getNoVehicleZone();
    Optional result = vinToVehicles.values().parallelStream().filter(v -> !v.getShape().intersects(noVehicleZone)).findFirst();

    return !result.isPresent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the loop:

```
for (VehicleSimView vehicle : vinToVehicles.values()) {
      future = executor.submit(new CanSpawnThread(vehicle, noVehicleZone));
      if(!future.get()){
          return false;
      }
  }
```

You are submitting to the executor, and then waiting for the future to complete before continuing and submitting the next one. This is still just a sequential loop.

Submit all of your callables to the executor, store the `Future`s in a list, and then check the elements of the list to see if they have completed.

Or, better, use a `CompletionService`, which will give you back Futures in the order in which they complete. Once you find a Future which returns false, cancel all the others and return.

Answer (score 0):

You submit a task and wait for finishing it. In this manner every thing is sequential, so you can't improve your performance. Submit all tasks and then wait to finish and check result. like this:

```
 private boolean canSpawnVehicle(SpawnPoint spawnPoint) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
  // TODO: can be made much faster.
  Rectangle2D noVehicleZone = spawnPoint.getNoVehicleZone();
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
  List<Future<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList();
  for (VehicleSimView vehicle : vinToVehicles.values()) {
      futures.add(executor.submit(new CanSpawnThread(vehicle, noVehicleZone)));          
  }
  for(Future<Boolean> future : futures) {
       if(!future.get()) {
          return false;
       }
  }
  executor.shutdown();
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You will suffer from head-of-line blocking here, since you check the futures for completion in order of submission. Use a CompletionService.

Comment: Also: "change to this" why? You need to explain your answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner comment added  ;)